# Missing dpkg after sudo apt-get update

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, apt

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

I've tried to update my raspberry, received 503 Service Unavailable message and now I can't install anything, because of missing dpkg directory..

root@raspberrypi:/sys/bus/w1/devices# **sudo apt-get update**

Ign ://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease
Ign ://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie Release.gpg
Ign ://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie Release
Err ://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages
503  Service Unavailable [IP: 93.93.128.133 80]
Err tp://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui armhf Packages
503  Service Unavailable [IP: 93.93.128.133 80]
Ign ://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign ://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en
Get:1 ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease [14.9 kB]
Get:2 ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main armhf Packages [8981 kB]
Get:3 ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages [37.5 kB]
Get:4 ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages [70.3 kB]
Get:5 ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi armhf Packages [1356 B]
Ign ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
Ign ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
Ign ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en
Fetched 9105 kB in 1min 32s (98.7 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch ://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages  **503  Service Unavailable** [IP: 93.93.128.133 80]

W: Failed to fetch ://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/ui/binary-armhf/Packages  **503  Service Unavailable** [IP: 93.93.128.133 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Now when I try update again:

root@raspberrypi:/tmp# **sudo apt-get update**

Hit ://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease
Hit ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
Hit ://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages
Hit ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main armhf Packages
Hit ://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui armhf Packages
Hit ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages
Hit ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages
Hit ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi armhf Packages
Ign ://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign ://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en
Ign ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
Ign ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
Ign ://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Now i can't install anything...

root@raspberrypi:/tmp# **apt-get download dpkg**

E: Could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

My lib directory:

root@raspberrypi:/tmp# **ls /var/lib/**

PackageKit  dhcpcd5    logrotate  openbox   polkit-1        samba      systemd  udisks2      usbutils  xkb
apt     ieee-data  nfs    pam       python      sgml-base  ucf  update-rc.d  vim       xml-core
container   lightdm    ntp    plymouth  python-support  sudo       udisks   urandom      xfonts

Can you guys please help? My connection is working fine..

Comment: This doesn't look like easily fixable. Would it be a big problem for you to reflash?

Comment: Looks like a corrupted file system. Seems like you're missing the folder `/var/lib/dpkg`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to reinstall dpkg manually by following the instructions used in this question. [How do I install packages without using a package manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110988/how-do-i-install-packages-without-using-a-package-manager) You unpack the package by

```
ar x package.deb
```

This gives you two archive files `control.tar.gz` and `data.tar.gz`.

`data.tar.gz` contains the program's files which are moved into place by the scripts in `control.tar.gz`. By moving the files over manually it may be possible to get dpkg to work.

If this doesn't work then you could backup your work then reflash the sd card with a image of Raspbian then when it is up and working copy your work back over to your sd card.

Comment: It might be an idea to include some of the information in the link in your answer, as to prevent link rot.

Comment: The OP does have `dpkg` installed, he just managed to remove the its working directory, `/var/lib/dpkg/`. Simply reinstalling the package won't fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are missing dpkg. It looks more like the update process caused a corruption on the lock file and now apt-get cannot safely set the dpkg lock to prevent running simultaneous updates.

One thing I typically do in a situation like this is restart the rpi (sudo reboot). This is a brute force way of basically killing anything that might be holding on to the lock or preventing dpkg from setting a lock.

After rebooting the rpi, if this still does not work, your next step, which is also quite brute force, is to forcibly remove the lock file. I believe you can do this with

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

As always, take care when using sudo rm anything because an incorrect typing could hose the system.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any missing or bugs in the packages use this command:

```
sudo apt-get update -fix-missing
```

If it doesn't work check this website 
and figure out that what's going on:

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/amp/

Answer (score 1):

Jessie is no longer supported (packages are no longer served by the Raspbian servers), so there's no point in trying to fix this now. Better start from scratch with a fresh image.

Answer (score 0):

So late in day, but the other alternative is to check your spelling.

`sudo dpgk -i filename.deb` is a non starter :D